# Problem in configuring OpenMPI-4.1.1 in Linux

Tags: installation, mpi, configure, openmpi, automake

I am trying to configure and install OpenMPI-4.1.1 in a Linux system.

I tried the following command first to configure:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

The last output lines are:

```
..........
Mellanox MXM: no
Open UCX: no
OpenFabrics OFI Libfabric: no
OpenFabrics Verbs: yes
Portals4: no
Shared memory/copy in+copy out: yes
Shared memory/Linux CMA: yes
Shared memory/Linux KNEM: no
Shared memory/XPMEM: no
TCP: yes
 
Resource Managers
-----------------------
Cray Alps: no
Grid Engine: yes
LSF: no
Moab: no
Slurm: yes
ssh/rsh: yes
Torque: no
 
OMPIO File Systems
-----------------------
DDN Infinite Memory Engine: no
Generic Unix FS: yes
IBM Spectrum Scale/GPFS: no
Lustre: no
PVFS2/OrangeFS: no
```

Then I tried the following command to install:

```
make all install
```

The output result is:

```
 cd . && /bin/sh /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/config/missing automake-1.15 --foreign
/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/config/missing: line 81: automake-1.15: command not found
WARNING: 'automake-1.15' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'Makefile.am' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'automake' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: that typically occurs when the timestamps are messed up. I suggest you retry from zero by un-tar-ing the official tarball into an empty directory.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do `reconfigure`, This usually happens in TAR archive files, I had the same problem.

Following is the command, in the extracted tarball path simply do:

```
autoreconf -fiv
```

then:

```
./configure --prefix=where/is/the/installation/path
```

then simply make and make install it:

```
make && make install
```

Surely if you do parallelization you would spend less time, for example:

```
make -j8 && make install
```

Comment: This only happens when timestamps are messed up. This is either caused by your environment (clock issue, wrong NFS timestamps, ...) or is a bug in the official tarball. If the latter, please triple check it and report it upstream.

Comment: Followed the suggestions by Elephant88 but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Followed all the suggestions.

1. Extracted the OpenMPI tar file using `tar -xvf openmpi-4.1.1.tar.gz`
2. `autoreconf -fiv`
3. ./configure --prefix=/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1
4. Make and install using `make && make install` but it gives

   Making all in config
   make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/config' make[1]: Nothing to be done for` all'.
   make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/config' Making all in contrib make[1]: Entering directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/contrib'
   make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'. make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/contrib'
   Making all in opal
   make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal' Making all in include make[2]: Entering directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/include'
   make  all-am
   make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/include' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/include'
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/include' Making all in datatype make[2]: Entering directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/datatype'
   CC       libdatatype_reliable_la-opal_datatype_pack.lo
   CC       libdatatype_reliable_la-opal_datatype_unpack.lo
   CCLD     libdatatype_reliable.la
   CC       opal_convertor.lo
   CC       opal_convertor_raw.lo
   CC       opal_copy_functions.lo
   CC       opal_copy_functions_heterogeneous.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_add.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_clone.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_copy.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_create.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_create_contiguous.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_destroy.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_dump.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_fake_stack.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_get_count.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_module.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_monotonic.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_optimize.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_pack.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_position.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_resize.lo
   CC       opal_datatype_unpack.lo
   CCLD     libdatatype.la
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/datatype' Making all in etc make[2]: Entering directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/etc'
   make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'. make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/etc'
   Making all in util
   make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/util' Making all in keyval make[3]: Entering directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/util/keyval'
   CC       keyval_lex.lo
   CCLD     libopalutilkeyval.la
   make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/util/keyval' make[3]: Entering directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/util'
   CC       alfg.lo
   CC       arch.lo
   CC       argv.lo
   CC       basename.lo
   CC       bipartite_graph.lo
   CC       cmd_line.lo
   CC       crc.lo
   CC       daemon_init.lo
   CC       ethtool.lo
   CC       error.lo
   CC       fd.lo
   CC       few.lo
   CC       if.lo
   CC       keyval_parse.lo
   CC       malloc.lo
   CC       net.lo
   CC       numtostr.lo
   CC       opal_environ.lo
   CC       opal_getcwd.lo
   CC       opal_pty.lo
   CC       os_dirpath.lo
   CC       os_path.lo
   CC       output.lo
   CC       path.lo
   CC       printf.lo
   CC       proc.lo
   CC       qsort.lo
   CC       show_help.lo
   CC       show_help_lex.lo
   CC       stacktrace.lo
   CC       strncpy.lo
   CC       sys_limits.lo
   CC       uri.lo
   CC       info_subscriber.lo
   CC       info.lo
   CCLD     libopalutil.la
   make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/util' make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/util'
   Making all in mca/base
   make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/base' CC       mca_base_close.lo CC       mca_base_cmd_line.lo CC       mca_base_component_compare.lo CC       mca_base_component_find.lo CC       mca_base_component_repository.lo CC       mca_base_components_open.lo CC       mca_base_components_close.lo CC       mca_base_components_select.lo CC       mca_base_list.lo CC       mca_base_open.lo CC       mca_base_var.lo CC       mca_base_pvar.lo CC       mca_base_var_enum.lo CC       mca_base_var_group.lo CC       mca_base_parse_paramfile.lo CC       mca_base_components_register.lo CC       mca_base_framework.lo CCLD     libmca_base.la make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/base'
   Making all in mca/common
   make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/common' make[2]: Nothing to be done for` all'.
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/common' Making all in mca/allocator make[2]: Entering directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/allocator'
   CC       base/allocator_base_frame.lo
   CCLD     libmca_allocator.la
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/allocator' Making all in mca/backtrace make[2]: Entering directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/backtrace'
   CC       base/backtrace_component.lo
   CCLD     libmca_backtrace.la
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/backtrace' Making all in mca/btl make[2]: Entering directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/btl'
   CC       base/btl_base_frame.lo
   CC       base/btl_base_error.lo
   CC       base/btl_base_select.lo
   CC       base/btl_base_mca.lo
   CCLD     libmca_btl.la
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/btl' Making all in mca/compress make[2]: Entering directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/compress'
   CC       base/compress_base_open.lo
   CC       base/compress_base_close.lo
   CC       base/compress_base_select.lo
   CC       base/compress_base_fns.lo
   CCLD     libmca_compress.la
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/compress' Making all in mca/crs make[2]: Entering directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/crs'
   CC       base/crs_base_open.lo
   CC       base/crs_base_close.lo
   CC       base/crs_base_select.lo
   CC       base/crs_base_fns.lo
   CCLD     libmca_crs.la
   GENERATE opal_crs.7
   Option package-version requires an argument
   Usage: ../../../config/make_manpage.pl --package-name= --package-version= --ompi-date= --opal-date= --orte-date= --input= --output= [--nocxx] [ --nofortran] [--nof08]
   make[2]: *** [opal_crs.7] Error 1
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/mca/crs' make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/ratheesh/openmpi-4.1.1/opal'
   make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

How to fix this issue?

Comment: same problem here